# Gnome top bar extension placement

Tags: gnome, top-bar

Is there an easy way to move the extensions to the other side of the clock in Gnome? As you can see in the screen shot, the right side is really cluttered, while the left is rather empty.

Also, is there a Gnome specific forum, or is it fine to ask the related questions here?

[image: Gnome top bar screenshot]

Edit: I'm using gnome 3.20 reqular version(not wayland).

Comment: You should be able to right-click and select move, if I remember correctly, just move them to the left. Also check out this extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/355/status-area-horizontal-spacing/ it removes the empty space between the icons

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work though, no matter if I press alt/super+alt/whatever else, right clicking or left clicking an icon will toggle its menu.

Comment: Better to change prefs on your system monitor and remove some of the panel eye candy.

Comment: @MarkKirby, the link to that extension was super helpful for me! I was also looking for a way to move my system performance extension to the left of the clock, but now it's not necessary with the space for my other app icons in the status bar drastically reduced.